# Android Studio. После изменения хотя бы одной строчки поведение приложения не меняется. Это нормально?

Tags: android, android-studio

В приложении есть несколько Activity. Есть кнопка, у неё установлен вот такой ClickListener:

```
private View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("Hello!");
        //button.setText("Bye!");
    }
};
```

Нажимаю Debug [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Приложение запускаю(дебажу) на телефоне.

В приложении изначальный текст на кнопке "Welcome". После нажатия на кнопку текст меняется на "Hello!". Всё хорошо.

Раскоменчиваю строчку `//button.setText("Bye!");` и нажимаю Debug [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

После нажатия на кнопку текст меняется на "Hello!". Почему?
Ставлю breakpoint на `button.setText("Hello!");` нажимаю ещё раз ловится breakpoint нажимаю F8 и указатель пролетает мимо `button.setText("Bye!");`. Это нормально?

Помогает только Rebuild Project.

Я не заметил с какого момента это стало проявляться, но сейчас так постоянно.
Возможно, что это нормально и нужно просто где-то поставить галочку чтобы Android Studio делала Rebuild Project по нажатию на Run и Debug.

UPD: Версия студии

Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

Comment: перекомпилировать пробовали?

Comment: @rjhdby это вы про Make Project (Ctrl+F9) ? иногда помогает, но не всегда и вот когда не помогает Make Project делаю Rebuild Project. По мне так это очень странно нажимать две кнопки, мне кажется что студия должна уж догадаться делать перекомпиляцию если исходник изменился. Или в этом нет логики? и я не прав?

Comment: Какая версия Android Studio и пробовали ли удалять приложение с телефона, а потом снова запускать среду?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov 
Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

Только что попробовал сделать как вы сказали.
Перед этим повторил возникновение проблемы. После удаления приложения, перезапуска среды и запуска Debug отрабатывает одна строчка. button.setText("Hello!");

Comment: @Sima, скорее всего дело в баге новой студии. Попробуйте решение отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49525674/3212712 и/или отключите `InstantRun`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Отключал, не помогло к моему сожалению.

Comment: @Sima, вы про первый или второй вариант? В моём случае только 1 сработал

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не уточнил.. я про InstantRun

Comment: @Sima, так таки попробуйте 1 вариант.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да видимо в этом и есть проблема проект был создан в Android Studio 3.0.1 и после обновления всё поломалось. Сейчас добавил Gradle-aware Make, как я и предполагал в самом вопросе =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это баг в новой версии студии `3.1` (точнее - в проектах, обновлённых до новой версии). Из конфигурации скрипта запуска пропала инструкция пересборки проекта при запуске. Чтобы это [починить надо](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49525674/3212712) открыть `Run` > `Edit Configuration` и посмотреть что есть под `Before launch:`, если там нет `Gradle-aware Make` как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то добавьте это, в меню создания оставив пустым поле с заданием. В итоге получится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]